# Error in finding if an imei number in valid in python (TypeError: not all arguments converted during string formatting)

Tags: python

I am making a python script that lets you entire an imei number then checks if it is valid, I keep getting an error

> Traceback (most recent call last):
> File "program.py", line 28, in 
> if isValidEMEI(n):
> File "program.py", line 19, in isValidEMEI
> d = (int)(n % 10)
> TypeError: not all arguments converted during string formatting
> the code is

```
    def sumDig( n ):
        a = 0
        while n > 0:
            a = a + n % 10
            n = int(n / 10)
    
        return a
    
    def isValidEMEI(n):
        s = str(n)
        l = len(s)
    
        if l != 15:
            return False
    
        d = 0
        sum = 0
        for i in range(15, 0, -1):
            d = (int)(n % 10)
            if i % 2 == 0:
                d = 2 * d
            sum = sum + sumDig(d)
            n = n / 10
        return (sum % 10 == 0)
    
    
    n = input("Enter number")
    if isValidEMEI(n):
        print("Valid IMEI Code")
    else:
        print("Invalid IMEI Code")
```

I have not really being sure what to try and do but I have looked up the error and nothing helpful/stuff I know to to interpret is showing up.
I am new to learning python so this will probalbly have a very simple sulution
I will update this with a "shortest replication of this error"
Thank you so much all help is welcome, this is for a challange I set myself so I am very determind to finish it

Comment: `n = input("Enter number")`  --> `n = int(input("Enter number"))`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I read inputs as numbers?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20449427/how-can-i-read-inputs-as-numbers)

Comment: @JohnnyMopp Yes, I had already done that, was reopening stack overflow to edit my post and post the answer for others if they have the same error, Thanks

Comment: JohnnyMopp comment points out the source of your error.  Additional items you should change: 1) `d = (int)(n % 10` change to `d = int(n % 10` i.e. clearer call to function int, 2) `n = n /10` to ` n //= 10` (integer rather than float division) and 3) don't use sum as a variable name since its the name of a popular function (use `sum_`).

Answer (score 0):

I have fixed it, replace `n = input("enter number")` with `n = int(input("Enter number"))`